# Is this a valid use of XML attributes?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I'm reading an undocumented file format that APPEARS to have some home-spun XML syntax.

```
<Paragraph Type="foo">
  <Text>Some text</Text>
  <Note ID="1">
    <Paragraph Alignment="Left" FirstIndent="0.00" Leading="Regular" LeftIndent="0.00" RightIndent="1.39" SpaceBefore="0" Spacing="1" StartsNewPage="No">
      <Text>note text.</Text>
    </Paragraph>
  </Note>
  <Text>Still more text.</Text>
</Paragraph>
```

In the example above, there's two different uses of `<Paragraph>`, both have different attributes.  Is that cool?  I thought the attributes that belonged to a specific `<tag>` needed to be consistent?

Comment: XML is pretty much freeform... you just need the XML declaration, a single root node of any valid name... and whatever structure of sub nodes and attributes you want.

Comment: Please define "cool".

Comment: By "cool", I meant "OK" -- or even "accepted practice".  I THOUGHT in my reading of the XML standards and reading postings here on SO that one of the arguments AGAINST choosing the attributes style with XML was that it lacked the flexibility to have new attributes added as a file format evolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many attributes in markup languages are optional, either because the specification defines default values or they represent data that really is optional. There's no problem with that.

HTML, for example, allows the `id` attribute on most elements. If you don't specify it, the element doesn't have an id, but it only needs one if you want to call it out somehow (e.g. by linking to it, selecting it in a stylesheet, finding it in the DOM with JS, etc).

It also has a `type` attribute on `input` elements. The spec says that if you don't specify it, then it is the same as specifying `type="text"`. This saves typing for the most common input type. Software implementing the spec knows what the default should be.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on your DTD or XSD otherwise it is valid.